# How to match and replace in a mouthful with PHP?

Tags: php, string

Something like this,but I don't want to do it 2 times:

```
preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);
$string = preg_replace($pattern,'',$string);
```

Comment: What is your exact pattern? And haystack?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific and actually describe what it is your are trying to do?

Comment: In your code the first line seems to be redundant. Unless you use matches later. But if you want to use matches later and also want to replace the strings then you need two regex

Comment: Of course I'll use it later:)

Answer (score 1):

OK,

so you want to capture the matches, and replace, in one function call. I'm guessing that you don't want to process a costly regex twice, otherwise I can see no good reason to want to make your code less readable.

Anyway,

you could try using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback). Something like:

```
class MatchReplace {

    var $matches;
    var $pattern;
    var $replacement;
    var $string;
    var $matchCount;

    function __construct($pattern, $replacement) {
        $this->replacement = $replacement;
        $this->pattern = $pattern;
    }

    function matchAndReplace($string) {
        $this->string = $string;

        var_dump($string);
        var_dump($this->pattern);

        return preg_replace_callback($this->pattern, 
                array($this, '_worker'), $string, -1, $this->matchCount);
    }


    function _worker($matches) {
        echo "Matches:\n";
        var_dump($matches);
    }
}
```

Example run:

```
echo "<pre>\n";
$m = new MatchReplace('|(abc)|', '');
echo "\nResult: \n".$m->matchAndReplace('XXXabcYYY');

echo "\n</pre>";
```

Output:

```
string(9) "XXXabcYYY"
string(7) "|(abc)|"
Matches:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "abc"
}

Result: 
XXXYYY
```

Comment: Unless your regex is crazy complicated, there is NO good reason to do this. Just run it twice: First match, then replace.

Comment: Regex like that is better run twice

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use str_replace() function instead of ereg_replace()  or preg_replace().

http://uk.php.net/str_replace

This will do all occurrences and only 1 command.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you are doing 2 completely separate things.

```
preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches); // return all the matches
$string = preg_replace($pattern,'',$string); // replace all the matches in the string
```

So you aren't actually doing anything twice. Unless you are using $matches somewhere further down the line, the first line is irrelevant if you are going to do the preg_replace afterwords anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all($pattern1,$string,$matches);
$result = preg_grep($pattern2, $matches);
```

Answer (score -1):

you mean something like this?

```
$string = preg_replace(preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches),'',$string);
```

**Update:**

I thought so you want something like this .. but you could see now that its not possible without complicating things (as @gnud answer). So answer is No, you can't do it in one line.

Comment: So probably you got the answer now that its not possible to do it in one line. :)